How to use internal mic with external headphones?
I want to use the internal mic while using the external headphones at the same time.
I have done some research, and it looks like the advice from Use built-in mic instead of earphone mic on call was to use an app called Lesser Audio Switch. But looking for this app today, I find it is not compatible with Android 14 (at least the Play Store says it isn't, please correct me if I'm wrong).
I was wondering if there is an alternative app or technique that could be used to achieve this effect. I have a Google Pixel 8 if that makes any difference. Thanks in advance.
